# using find with rsync is failing in a way I can't understand

Tags: bash, find, rsync

I am trying to synchronise two directories, omitting certain files.

```
find . -type f  -print0  |rsync -vupt -0 --files-from=- . /tmp/test
```

This copies every file  of course, but works as expected

The problem arises when I try to limit the files copied. So if I want to copy all but the files ending ".part" :

```
find . -type f -\! -iname "*.part" -print0  |rsync -vupt -0 --files-from=- . /tmp/test
```

But this fails to copy anything at all.

If I remove the pipe I can see that find is outputting a stream that looks just like the kind of output from the first command but minus the file names I don't want to copy.

(I've tries -not and -name alternatives too without luck)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` negation is not a command, but an *operator*. You can use `! -iname "*.part"` to negate that single expression.